# Find if the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{(2x+1)(x^4-6x^3+9x^2)^{1/3}}\,dx$ converges without solving it

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve this integral, but without any success.

Is there a way to tell if the integral is convergent or divergent without actually solving it? Am I missing something?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\arctan x}{(2x+1)(x^4-6x^3+9x^2)^{1/3}}\,dx$$

Comment: You are not asked to compute the integral.  Look how the integrand behaves around $x=0$ and at $\infty$. Don(t forget the possible discontinuities

Comment: what is artcg(x)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Instead of sharing picture we use LaTeX. Please be aware of that

Comment: @JamesChiu I believe the $\operatorname{arctg}(x)$ refers to $\arctan (x)$.

Comment: Hello and sorry, now the integral is in LaTex

Comment: Let $f(x)=\frac{\arctan x}{(2x+1)\sqrt[3]{x^4-6x^3+9x^2}}$. Find with proof constants $a,\,b,\,c,\,d$ such that $f(x)\sim ax^b$ for small $x>0$, and $f(x)\sim cx^d$ for large $x>0$. You'll find $a,\,c>0$, so convergence occurs iff $b>-1$ and $d<-1$. Hint: for small $x$, $\arctan x\sim x$; for large $x>0$, $\arctan x\sim\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\arctan x}{(2x+1)(x^4-6x^3+9x^2)^{1/3}}\,dx$$ converges. We'll consider an initial and final segment separately and bound them both.

Let's look at the factors. For large $x$ we have

$$\arctan(x) \le \pi/2 \qquad \dfrac{1}{(2x+1) } \simeq \frac{1}{2x} \qquad \dfrac{1}{ (x^4-6x^3+9x^2)^{1/3}} \simeq \frac{1}{x^{4/3}}$$

. . . since in the last factor the $x^4$ dominates.

Make the above formal and use it to compare some final segment of the integral to

$$\int_{x}^{\infty} \dfrac{\pi/2}{(2x )x^{4/3}}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{x}^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{ x^{7/3}} $$

For small $x$ we have

$$\arctan(x) \simeq  x -\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5} - \ldots \qquad \dfrac{1}{(2x+1) } \simeq \frac{1}{2} \qquad \dfrac{1}{ (x^4-6x^3+9x^2)^{1/3}} \simeq \dfrac{1}{ ( 9x^2)^{1/3}}$$

. . .  since in the last factor the $x^2$ term dominates.

Use the above similar to before to bound some integral over an initial segment.

[Now consider the integral near $3$ where it blows up:](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o9cwvbg1lk)

[image]

This time write $ x^4-6x^3+9x^2= x^2 (x-3)^2 $ and so

$$ \dfrac{1}{ (x^4-6x^3+9x^2)^{1/3}}  = \frac{1}{x^{2/3} (x-3)^{2/3}}$$

Since everything else is bounded you only need to show the integral of $\frac{1}{ (x-3)^{2/3}}$ around $3$ converges.

We conclude the integrals at $0,3$ and $\infty$ all converge. Since the function is continuous everywhere else it is bounded over the remaining domain hence has finite integral.